# Spree -- Remove/Clear previous promotions when a new promotion applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am maintaining an old project that is using branch 2-4-stable of [spree](http://git://github.com/spree/spree.git)

lets say I used a promotion with coupon code AAAA at /cart and than I changed my mind and used promotion BBBB at /cart. Now when I change my mind second time and try to add promotion AAAA /cart it says

> The coupon code has already been applied to this order

The code that checks in promotion has been applied is present at

> ....../bundler/gems/spree-651f537d0d89/core/app/models/spree/promotion_handler/coupon.rb

```
  def promotion_exists_on_order?(order, promotion)
    order.promotions.include? promotion
  end
```

I want order.promotions to only contain one promotion of coupon code.

Any idea how this can be achieved?